# Why does C not truncate this?

Tags: c, computer-science

I'm currently reading the K&R Book on C, I'm currently doing the temperature converter code and it says here that `cels = 5 * (fahr-32) / 9;` instead of just multiplying it by 5/9 we multiply by 5 and then divide by 9 since it truncates, but my code doesn't truncate it am I doing something wrong or is this a new feature in Modern C? here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int fahr, cels;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;
    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        cels = (fahr - 32) * 5/9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, cels);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Instead of `cels = (fahr - 32) * 5/9;` I did `cels = 5/9 *(fahr - 32);` and it truncates the code. Why does the other one work while the other does not?

Comment: Would this help? "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Comment: My program works, I just dont understand why C doesn't truncate it anymore? Is this a new feature of modern C compilers?

Comment: What the book means is that you can't do this: `cels = 5/9 * (fahr - 32);` The reason is that multiplication and division are evaluated from left to right, so `5 * a / 9` and `a * 5 / 9` both do the multiplication first, but `5 / 9 * a` divides first.

Comment: Yeah I just did that and it truncates it, but why does it not do it on the other code?

Comment: When you say doesn't truncate, what do you mean? Do you mean you are getting floating-point output? -- impossible. Integer division and output with the `"%d"` format specifier can result in nothing but integer output.

Comment: @airismything you are not asking a clear question ... you are leaving out the printout that is produced by the program

Comment: What I meant was it's not displaying as 0 as its should be but I just found out the answer to that lol.

Comment: "Truncate" does not necessarily mean "truncate to zero".  Truncate means "drop the fractional part of the number".  That's what's happening in your program.  For example, instead of printing something like `104.444444` for the 220F conversion, your program prints `104`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I see, thanks!

Comment: And just to be clear, what's happening when you change the expression to `5/9 *(fahr - 32)` is that the `5/9` is evaluated using integer division (which truncates). 5/9 is 0.55556.  When that is truncated you actually do get 0.  And you know what happens when 0 is an operand in multiplication...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `(fahr - 32) * 5/9`, that is the same as `((fahr - 32) * 5)/9`, since `*` and `/` have the same precedence and are left associative.  But when you do `5/9 *(fahr - 32)`, that is the same as `(5/9) *(fahr - 32)` for the same reason.

In all cases, the integer divide truncates towards 0, so what matters is whether you multiply *then* divide (which gives you the "correct" result) or divide *then* mulitply (which always gives you 0 as `5/9` truncates to 0)

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now lol. Your explanation was clear and concise :)